# Looking for a title to a 80s sci fi film

Tags: story-identification, movie

Does anyone know the title of an 80s or early 90s sci-fi flick where there's a group in an underground facility and there's some type of monster mutants chasing them. The only part I remember at the end is that they need to escape (it's only a male and female character I think that are left surviving) by climbing up a hatch and when they do it's onto a snowy field. The monsters are chasing them too and you see them come up out of the hatch and I think at that point the facility underground explodes.

Apologies that this is very vague and sounds like every other sci-fi flick of the 80s but I never saw it again and it stuck in my mind for some reason.

Comment: What language?  What country was it made in?  When did you see it?

Answer (score 7):

I know you said 80s / early 90s, but you might be referring to the first ***X-Files*** film, released in 1998.  At the end of the film:

- Mulder and Scully (male and female!) are trying to escape from an alien ship / hybridization facility buried underground in Antarctica
- alien-human hybrids are chasing them as they run through the ship
- they manage to crawl out of the ship through an exhaust hatch (the aliens almost get them in the process)
- the ship, having detected the anti-alien vaccine that Mulder injected into the facility, unearths itself and flies away; the take-off of the ship destroys the aliens that were behind them in the hatch
- Mulder and Scully find themselves on a snow-covered ice patch as the ship departs

Here are the scenes:

Comment: It was definitely a US film and not X-Files lol.  I've seen the x-files movie a few times. I would say I saw this 20 years ago <.<  , and never saw it again.

Comment: @PedroChinoMoscoso : The X-Files film is a US film.  Do you mean that the particular scene you saw was set somewhere in the US?  Thanks for coming back to let us know.  I'll keep looking.  :-)