# 80s/90s Adventure Sci-fi Movie about Biological Lab

Tags: story-identification

This movie used to play on WSVN 7, Miami, FL's local Fox station, a lot during its late night movies either in the late 80s or early 90s.

The setting is some kind of biological lab, and there was an accident of some sort.  The two protagonists (a male and a female) must escape with their lives, while avoiding the contamination.

If I recall correctly, the contaminant/virus/whatever was "plant-like", insofar as it would turn people into plant-like mutants.  (This is NOT swamp thing, another WSVN7 staple during that time period).  But I could be misremembering this detail.

The movie MIGHT be related to

[Looking for a title to a 80s sci fi film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109426/looking-for-a-title-to-a-80s-sci-fi-film)

But I don't necessarily remember the snowy field.

Comment: It sounds a bit like the Roger Corman production *The Terror Within* from 1989, which also ends like the other Q described (you can currently watch the whole thing [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsZ70rztTfk)), but TBH I'm not 100% sure it's what either of you are after.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like [The Andromeda Strain (1971)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066769/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) . There's no monster or blob in this movie; it's a virus from space which had the potential to infect/kill everyone on Earth. The facility was equipped with a "fail-safe" - a nuclear bomb for which a detonation countdown was initiated, but then had to be aborted after the scientists learned that the explosion would have fed and disseminated the virus instead of destroying it.

Comment: Could be "Invasion of the Body Snatchers / 1978" - alien plants were in the pods and they were replacing real people.

Comment: Not an episode of the early [X-Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files), I watched them all. ("The original television series aired from September 10, 1993 to May 19, 2002")

Answer (score 3):

It might be [Warning Sign (1985)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090293/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_61).

It features an accident in a secret germ warfare lab. Plants crop up heavily because the cover for the building is an Agricultural Research Center. The infection causes people to mutate and become violent.

The sheriff's wife is the security guard for the building at the time of the incident and is sealed inside, having a period of the film where she works with the [male] chief administrator to escape. Later, she meets up with her husband and the two of them try to save everyone.

Comment: I watched the trailer and it looks like a very plausible guess.  Thank you!